# Dynamically creating a select and then on change ajax call to append html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, select

I have navigation with add tab function while, adding a tab the content div gets populated with a select box. Now from the options of the select box on changing will call respective forms and get appended to the page.

index.php

```
<ul id="myTab" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#q1"  role="tab" >Form 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="add-contact" >Add Forms</a></li>
</ul>
```

Above nav adds tab and creates the below div in index.php

```
<div class="tab-content">
     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="q1">
      <form id="id1" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
          <select id="" class="form-control" name="">
             <option value="form1">Form 1</option>
             <option value="form2">Form 2</option>
          </select><form>
</div>
```

The content in the div tab-content gets dynamically created

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('select').bind('change', function(){
      $.ajax({ 
    url: "htmlforms.php", 
    context: document.body, 
    success: function(html){
    $("#contentForm").append(html);
  }});
});});
```

Now what i need is on changing the options i need to add the form using ajax call and get appended in the div tab-content.

Comment: What is not working how you expect? FYI, that `select` event attachment looks like it [needs delegating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements).

Comment: On changing the options in the select box is not calling the ajax from and eventually not appending the form

Comment: Delegate your event handler, see the link in my last comment (http://stackoverflow.com/q/203198/1612146)

Comment: @George can you please edit the code of what you want me to add, didn't understand from the example link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you must delegate your event handler for the `change` event on your `select`. This is because the `select` is located within content that gets modified/added after the initial creation of the DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', 'select', function(){
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "htmlforms.php", 
            context: document.body, 
            success: function(html){
            $("#contentForm").append(html);
        }});
    });
});
```

[jQuery API Documentation for .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)